# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gffpandas'

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror

Although I installed the below library, I am not able to use it:

```
$ pip3 install gffpandas
Requirement already satisfied: gffpandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.2.0)
$ python
Python 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul  1 2019, 14:38:56) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gffpandas.gffpandas as gffpd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gffpandas'
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed? Try using `python -m pip install gffpandas`

Comment: Or try initiating python with ```python3``` instead of ```python```

Comment: Yes, I am using an anaconda environment. `python3 -m pip install gffpandas` worked but why?